# How to display the value of a SharedPreference without entering the dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, sharedpreferences

I have some Shared Preferences in my application defined in an XML file. They are EditTextPreferences. I want to display the existing values on the Preference screen so that the user doesn't have to enter the Preference Edit Dialog to see the current value of the Preference. The defaultValue is only visible in the Dialog screen. I want to see the defaultValue in the main preferences screen - maybe in the place of android:summary. How can I do this?

```
<EditTextPreference
  android:key="PREF_LT_500"
  android:title="Step 1"
  android:summary="I dont want a summary - I want to show current value"
  android:inputType="numberDecimal" 
  android:defaultValue="0.8952"
  android:dialogTitle="Enter Blah " />
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try:

```
yourPrefrence.getText();
```

Or a more generic solution:

```
SharedPreferences p = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

String ans = p.getString(keyStr, defaultValue);
```

When this is a Context, keyStr is the key & defaultValue is a default value in case the key is not found (usually "")

Comment: This solution gives me access to the value in my code. I want to display the existing value to the user on the preferences screen.

Comment: In that case you can use:
yourPrefrence.setSummary(summary);
I'm not sure but it sound reasonable that you can't set in by XML because the preference's value is not constant and it may change, so you need to set it dynamically by code... Hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of trying something like that